# Discord.py - Interactions - Buttons

Tags: button, discord.py, bots, interaction

I've been trying to create Buttons for my Discord bot but it seems like I have something wrong, I just can't figure out what it is.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    button = Button(
        style=ButtonStyle.PRIMARY,
        custom_id="primary",
        label="Blue button",
    )
    await ctx.send("Hello World!", components=button)
```

I also have the following imports:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import time
import interactions
from interactions import Button, ButtonStyle, SelectMenu, SelectOption, ActionRow
```

What I expect: The bot replying to command !test with the message "Hello World!" and a button with the text 'Blue button' attached to that message.

What it does: Absolutely nothing.

Now I have been staring at this for quite a while, so fair chance I've missed something rather simple, but I'd appreciate the help either way :)

Comment: I took a quick look at the docs of `discord-py-interactions` and they suggest that this is for *slash commands*, not *message commands*, so `!test` doesn't do or trigger anything. Consider using discord.py v2.0 (currently in beta/dev) if you want to use new Discord features.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instal the `discord_components` Module .
`pip install discord_components`

Then this code should work for you :

```
from discord_components import *

bot = ComponentsBot(command_prefix="?")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    button = Button(
        style=ButtonStyle.blue,
        custom_id="primary",
        label="Blue button",
    )
    await ctx.send("Hello World!", components=[button])
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Just make sure to use: pip install --upgrade discord-components
Otherwise import Discord won't work anymore.

Comment: `discord-components` is an archived library that was to be used as a substitute until discord.py 2.0 was released. Now that discord.py 2.0 has been released and there are many other stable, maintained forks (nextcord, pycord), I don't think it's reasonable to suggest using `discord-components`.